# Change table to divs on imagefield values unlimited

Tags: theming

Is it possible to output the Image Field values so that it doesn't use tables but divs?

[image: My markup]

Comment: Your not being specific enough about what your using. This is not just an imagefield.

Comment: @AlexGill I think it is an image field, but not the actual output.  It looks like an edit page.  That said, you are completely right; without more information this is not *directly* answerable (although I'm sure a vague answer could be provided).

Comment: It looks like an admin screen with Tabledrag and also has something called Manual Crop. Do you want to change the admin screen from tables to divs and still want to have drag-sorting? You've got a lot of work to do.

Comment: It's the edit page of my user profile.
It's just so fustrating with all those tables.
Its an imagefield with multiple values.
Is there somekind of templte to change the tables to divs.
I know i can display block and stuff but it's just double work.

Comment: To be honest, I think it's be more trouble than it's worth changing them to divs.  Tabledrag would stop working for a start, and tables aren't *really* a problem in situations like this.

Comment: But when i use display block on the tr, the tabledrag stops working. WHY?

Comment: @MyRevenge What Chapabu is saying is that Tables are fine when used in correct context, e.g. to display tabular data. It's only NOT ok when you use tables for layout of a page.